# ¿Por qué live Server no me funciona en tiempo real en VS Code?

Tags: html5, vscode

Live server no me hace los cambios en tiempo real cuando hago cambios y guardo el archivo que estoy trabajando en VS Code, solo cuando actualizo la pagina en el navegador, cosa que se puede realizar sin necesidad de la extensión, ¿no se si debería a mi farewall o es cosa de la extensión?.

Me gustaría saber como solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: Tienes activado el autoguardado amigo?